# How to run a single test case in nose2

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose2

I'd like to run a single test contained in a subclass of `unittest.TestCase` using `nose2` following [How to run specific test in Nose2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890087/how-to-run-specific-test-in-nose2), but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using the following example script, which I've named `mickey_mouse_test.py`:

```
import unittest

class TestMickeyMouse(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1plus1is2(self):
        self.assertTrue(1+1 == 2)

    def test_to_uppercase(self):
        self.assertEqual("hello".upper(), "HELLO")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

If I run `nose2 mickey_mouse_test` in the same directory, it runs all the tests in the module:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Scratch$ nose2 mickey_mouse_test
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

However, if I try to run just `test_to_uppercase` like so I get an error:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Scratch$ nose2 mickey_mouse_test.test_to_uppercase
E
======================================================================
ERROR: mickey_mouse_test.test_to_uppercase (nose2.loader.LoadTestsFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module 'mickey_mouse_test' has no attribute 'test_to_uppercase'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

If I use the `-s` option I still get an error, albeit a different one:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Scratch$ nose2 -s mickey_mouse_test.test_to_uppercase
E
======================================================================
ERROR: mickey_mouse_test.test_to_uppercase (nose2.loader.LoadTestsFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError: /home/kurt/Documents/Scratch/mickey_mouse_test.test_to_uppercase is not a directory

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I've also tried reading the "Specifying tests to run" section in http://nose2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html, in which it is stated that the 'Python object part' should be a 'dotted name'. I don't see why in this case, `mickey_mouse_test.test_to_uppercase` is not a 'dotted name'. Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run specific test in Nose2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890087/how-to-run-specific-test-in-nose2)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to run just `test_to_uppercase` without using `nose2` (following [Running single test from unittest.TestCase via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971735/running-single-test-from-unittest-testcase-via-command-line)):

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Scratch$ python mickey_mouse_test.py TestMickeyMouse.test_to_uppercase
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```